# GDAL Java bindings GDAL 2.0.0 in Eclipse

Tags: gdal, java

Does anyone know a quick way to use GDAL Java Bindings in Java Eclipse?

It should be GDAL > 2.0.0 in order to support KEA datatypes. GDAL-Java from OSGEO4W seems to be obsolete.

I am working on Windows 10 on a 64Bit processor and Eclipse Mars.

Answer (score 3):

Setting up GDAL for Java IDE (in Windows) requires the following two steps:

***Setting GDAL in system/server using the following steps.***

- You can download the executable GDAL packages (stable releases) from [GIS internals](http://gisinternals.com). Choose compiler (Microsoft Visual C) & architecture (32bit or 64bit) depending upon your PC and download the compiled binaries zip file (not the Compiled libraries and headers).
- Extract the zip file and save in some drive preferably C drive.
- Now create/append the following data in your PC Environmental Variables (Computer --> Properties -->Advance System Settings -->Environment variables):

  **CREATE/APPEND        VARIABLE                   VALUE                              REQUIREMENT**

CREATE                         GDAL_DATA                  C:\gdal\bin\gdal-data          MANDATORY
       CREATE                         GDAL_DRIVER_PATH  C:\gdal\bin\gdal\plugins      MANDATORY
       APPEND                         PATH                             C:\gdal\bin                           MANDATORY
       APPEND                         PATH                             C:\gdal\bin\gdal\apps          OPTIONAL

- The last append option is required if you want to use the gdal tools from any location in your PC.
- Now you test the GDAL tools. Open Command prompt in your PC and type gdalinfo --formats. This command will list out the typr of raster formats it supports. Alternatively ogrinfo --formats will display vector formats.

***Setting GDAL for project in Netbeans/Eclipse IDE.***

- Copy and paste following four/one dll file(s) from C:\gdal\bin\gdal\java to your **jdk bin** folder.

  ```
  gdalconstjni.dll
  gdaljni.dll
  ogrjni.dll
  osrjni.dll
  ```

  OR

  ```
  gdalalljni.dll (in higher versions of gdal v2.3.0 and above)
  ```
- You need to add **gdal.jar** file (from C:\gdal\bin\gdal\java) in the JAVA BUILD PATH Library location.
- Now your java project will work with GDAL. Just ensure the GDAL package and JDK architecture (x86/x64).

Note: If you forget to do this you get an exception while executing your code as Exception in thread "main" **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError**.

Note: For more information on gdal java projects, visit [GeoSpatial Blogs](http://geospatialearth.in/blogs.php)

Comment: I wasn't able to run `gdalinfo --formats` from cmd, possibly because it's called `gdalinfo.exe`?  When I ran that I got an error saying "The code execution cannot proceed because LIBPQ.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem", and the same error again for SSLEAY32.dll and LEBEAY32.dll.  I chose the 64-bit version though.

Comment: @Conan you can search in C drive which folder has this DLLs. Then you can add that folder location in path environmental variable. I hope this should work.